# change the url in facebook comments code?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

on my website I have more than 200 pages and I want to add facebook comments feature to my website. I ran to this problem is that I have to change the code (the url) for each page. I do not want to change the code for every page. If you can see the second piece of code contain Url goes here can I include a method like `location.href` so that it can use the current url of the page. can I do this ? I do not care if it is php, javascript, or anything ealse.

Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening `<body>` tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=324524777119";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="Url Goes Here" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `div` and then dynamically create its contents with the `innerHTML` method in JavaScript
where it will be your `fb-comments` tag. You can get the current page with `document.location.href`.

After you create the `fb-comments` tag dynamically and render it inside the `div`, you need to reparse its contents so the XFBML is interpreted. You can do it with the `FB.XFBML.parse()` method.

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById('myCommentsDiv');  
mydiv.innerHTML = 
   '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="' + document.location.href + '" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></fb:comments>';  
FB.XFBML.parse(mydiv);
```

Comment: I tried the code you gave me, but it is showing me random comments from random people.

Comment: Try "View source" in your browser to see the html that your code rendered.

Comment: Can you give us a demo/sample page url for us to see what you've got?

Comment: Ahhh.  Your syntax is incorrect.  You should put that code in normal javascript script tags. Ensure it runs in the document.fbAsyncInit.  Also ensure you have the myCommentsDiv.  Looks like you have quite a bit of learning to do. Take your time.  You can get it.

Comment: what do you mean "Ensure it runs in the document.fbAsyncInit" ? any way this is the code I have now...

Comment: '<script>
    var mydiv = document.getElementById('myCommentsDiv');  
mydiv.innerHTML = 
   '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="' + document.location.href + '" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></fb:comments>';  
FB.XFBML.parse(mydiv);  
</script>'

Comment: fbAsyncInit is talked about here:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: does that mean that I have to build a ap for facebook comments ?

Comment: What errors did you get (if any) when you implemented the above code?

Answer (score 2):

This can be used for getting the page url on the initial load.

```
<?php
function get_current_page()
{
   $page_url = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
   $page_url .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
   return $page_url;
}
?>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo get_current_page(); ?>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

If the url is changed after the initial page loads the FB.XFBML.parse() needs to be called to reload the comment box.  This is good for ajax sites that do not do a full page reload when changing state.

Answer (score 1):

A simple suggestion is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<div class="fb-comments" data-href="' + document.location.href + '"
 data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>');   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: found the solution here:
[Different Facebook comment box after each ajax call](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8911425/different-facebook-comment-box-after-each-ajax-call)

You have to remove the box completely and put it back and call FB.XFBML.parse()

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

I defined the URL like this:

```
define('URL_FB','http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

and then I echoed like this:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo URL_FB; ?>" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

Hope to be clear enough. :)